# fixing the Unicode rendering in flutter

Tags: android, ios, dart, cross-platform, flutter

I am new to flutter, I manage to receive the data from server and decoded it as well, when i tried to display in the text, it shows like below.

[image]

Code to display the text

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sachchirashifal/model/serverdata.dart';

class RashiFalDetail extends StatelessWidget {
  Data rashi;

  RashiFalDetail({this.rashi});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: new Text(rashi.desc, style: new TextStyle(
        fontSize: 18.0,
        color: Colors.black
      ))
    );
  }
}
```

Any suggestions will be great, Thank u.

Comment: Is it the same on a real device?

Comment: unfortunately i have to say yes @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: I'd suggest to file an issue (with the output from `flutter doctor -v`)

Comment: could you please provide that text shows in the phone . So I can test with my device

Comment: Is the text UTF8 encoded?

Comment: Yes , I have done it, But still i could not figure out why i still getting this.@GünterZöchbauer

Comment: I found the error was not with unicode encoding. I tried with small text length it works fine. But when i copy same text for multiple times and make large then the big text is shown as above figure. I guess i am making mistake with wrapping the text or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Your text has html tags. It should be rendered/viewed as HTML.
Check this [package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_html_textview/). This should solve your problem of hindi rendering as well.

**NOTE**: If you are unable to install this package, update your flutter as this package is very new and built with the latest flutter.

Comment: I will try this

Comment: This removed the html tags but text are still showing like above.

Comment: Okay. have you tried hindi font? download and add a hindi font in pubspec.yaml and appl that font only to the hindi text. Do let me know what happens!

Comment: I tried with Hindi font aswell but i guess the problem is with Text widget itself

Comment: Have you tried other Hindi texts. Could be that actual text is not in the correct format.

Comment: I have same problem. I tried with Nepali Unicode fonts. No luck yet.

Comment: I still get this issue. Has anyone been able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same issue.
Try [converting your unicode text to Krutidev](http://wrd.bih.nic.in/font_KtoU.htm) or any local devnagri font style and import that font. this will solve your issue.

Add font file in ttf format in your assets and load in a variable like this

```
final ttf = await fontFromAssetBundle('Kruti-Regular.ttf');
```

then call the text widget.

```
Text("xzke ", style: pw.TextStyle(font: ttf)
```

Output of that text widget is ग्राम while in normal unicode it was displayed as [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6832O.png)